# How to send video from a PC to a SDTV

Tags: graphics-card, tv

so I've got a relatively powerful PC with an Asus Dark Knight Geforce 9800 GTX+ graphics card and I would like to somehow play the video on my SDTV for TV shows, films etc. The only outputs my GFX card has are HDTV-out and DVI x 2. How can I do this? Do I need to buy some PCI TV card or whatever?

Please don't suggest me to just get a HDTV and be over with it. I've got a reason to stay with my SDTV for another year or so :)

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you told us what connections your tv takes (obviously it takes coax and composite)? what about component? Svideo?

Comment: My TV has a S-Video input and the yellow/white/red inputs. The DVIs on my gfx card are taken by two PC monitors.

Comment: all 9 pin din outputs are NOT the same. some cards use a 7 pin din and are not the same as 9 pin din pin allocation. the trick with s-video of breaking off the plastic pin may not work with 9 pin din now try finding a card that fits a pci slot that has s-video out or indeed any din type connector, the g-force 9400 has but the card doesn't support tv out, all you can run off that port is vga adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a graphics card that also has (analog) TV outputs, i.e. component/S-video/composite.  The typical connector used for this TV output is a 7- or 9-pin DIN jack on the bracket.  A dongle/adapter will have the mating DIN plug on one end and standard video connectors on the other end.

If the new graphics adapter does not have TV out, then you will have to purchase a VGA-to-composite converter, which is about another US$100, in addition to to the graphics adapter.

BTW "SDTV" could refer to either analog or digital standard definition television. Presumably you really mean you have an analog NTSC/PAL/SECAM TV.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a second card.  You can get a device or cable that will convert the DVI connections to a type that your television will support.  What you need will depend on what your television has as far as inputs, but a couple of examples can be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0034HNY40) or [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Q6RL9Q).

Comment: My TV has a S-Video input and the yellow/white/red inputs. The DVIs on my gfx card are taken by two PC monitors.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Please make sure when asking questions in the future that you provide all relevant details.  My guess would be, then, that the HDTV output on your graphics card cannot be used.  For many graphics cards nowadays with three outputs, you can only use 2 of 3 at a time.  That being the case, you either need to invest in a second graphics card and use the outputs on that or in a TV card/device.

Comment: Thanks BBlake and sorry for lacking information. I guess I will look for some cheapo PCI gfx card just for this purpose.

Comment: @TomaszRykala If you're planning to buy a new card, make sure that it will work with the standard your TV uses. I remember that for quite some time some nVidia cards couldn't output PAL for example, due to driver problems.